# Drag a container vertically up and down to a certain level flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, gesturedetector, flutter-container

I am new to gestures and I don't get any proper solution for achieving my request,
Can anyone help me in dragging a container up and down vertically to a certain point?.

I need to achieve something like the below image.
Thanks in advance.

[image: container at bottom]

[image: dragged container]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [draggable home](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_home) if you want a ready-made similar effect.
If you want to replicate the goggle maps UI one-on-one, consider reading [DraggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html) and make one your own.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But using DraggableScrollableSheet is not possible for each index of the list view.